# Concatenating 2 char* produces weird result

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

Off the bat - I am brand new to C++.

So I'm dealing with a situation where I have two `char*` which need to be concatenated and passed into another method. This should be simple but I just cannot figure it out...

**First char and the `getMetaData()` method declaration for reference**

```
virtual const char *getMetaData() const = 0
char* metaChar = const_cast<char*>(result->getMetaData());
```

**Second char and the `getUniqueTargetId()` method declaration for reference**

```
virtual const char *getUniqueTargetId() const = 0
char* idChar = const_cast<char*>(result->getUniqueTargetId());
```

Now I need to combine them to pass into the method `setUserData()`. Here is the declaration for it:

```
virtual bool setUserData(void *userData) = 0
```

Now if I pass each of those `char` into the `setUserData()` method individually, it works fine. If I try concatenate them and then pass the result, it either produces `nil` or some random characters which look like Latin.

I've tried the following (plus a few others and variations):

1. Converting each to NSString, concatonate those, convert back to `char`
2. Trying to concatonate the two `char` arrays
3. Casting to all sorts of different things and back and forth
4. Turning it off and back on again
5. Checked the type of `metaChar` and the result of option 1 above and they correspond - apparently exactly the same

Again - I'm new round these parts... There is probably something obvious I'm missing but it's been a number of hours now and this seems like a problem which shouldn't take up this much time.

Comment: Using `const_cast` to remove `const` and then using the result of the cast is UB

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: only if you use the result of the cast in a non-const context.

Comment: @Bathsheba, true, I should have said "may result in UB".

Comment: And only if the object was originally declared `const`.

Comment: @TartanLlama: absolutely!

Comment: *This should be simple but I just cannot figure it out.* -- That is because it isn't so simple, and the reason why `std::string` exists.  -- *I have two char* which need to be concatenated* -- A `char *` is a pointer, not a string. Just that misunderstanding leads to misleading attempts of "concatenation".

Answer (score 2):

Lots of nasty `const_cast` and conversions to `void*` here, but I assume you're given these methods so can't do a lot about that.

Assuming that `setUserData` takes a copy of the string passed internally, then for two `char*` "strings" `foo` and `bar`, you could use

`setUserData(const_cast<void*>(reinterpret_cast<const void*>((std::string(foo) + std::string(bar)).c_str())));`

Here I'm relying on `std::string`'s overload of `+` to perform the concatenation. `c_str()` returns a `const char*` and is valid for the lifetime of the statement. I'm *hoping* that `setUserData` takes a deep copy of the "string": check the function documentation. If I'm not correct then this approach is a non-starter. Note that we're casting to `void*` via a `const_cast` which I don't particularly like, but it's good to be explicit about this kind of thing.

If you "own" all the functions, then ditch all this `char*` nonsense and use `std::string` from the get-go.

Comment: It might be worth noting that if `setUserData` just stores the pointer you pass in, it's UB party time.

Comment: I try to make that clear with "Assuming that setUserData takes a copy of the string passed internally". But I'm starting to think that this question is pretty unanswerable.

Comment: Yeah, I knew what you meant, but a newbie might not :). Your edit clarifies nicely.

Comment: (Taken me this long to respond as I've been battling with XCode... It's still throwing errors when trying to `#include <string>` but still somehow compiles... Anyway) I'm getting the error `Reinterpret_cast from 'const value_type *' (aka 'const char *') to 'void *' casts away qualifiers`.. Busy researching it

Comment: @ByronCoetsee: I've bunged in yet another cast. If anything this illustrates how flaky things get when working with `char*`.

Comment: Well that got rid of the error (woohoo) but unfortunatly it ain't working still... Seems to be `nil` on the other side... Even comparing types in xcode show them as equal and when printing out the result of your code it's correct... So I don't understand...

Answer (score 0):

So I found my solution eventually - thank you all for the help though!

I basically took the long way round and yes, this does seem rather superfluous but for a complete beginner (like a week's worth of experience - I'm being forced here) it works...

```
char* metaChar = const_cast<char*>(result->getMetaData());
char* idChar = const_cast<char*>(result->getUniqueTargetId());

char *buffer = new char[(int)strlen(metaChar)+(int)strlen(idChar)+5]();
strncat(buffer, idChar, strlen(idChar));
strncat(buffer, metaChar, strlen(metaChar));
strncat(buffer, "\0", 2);

newTrackable->setUserData(buffer);
```

The `+5` is there just to provide a buffer (ha... see what I did there?) for a `char` or whatever that might require more space. Rather safe than sorry.